# Dropdown not resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I am using flex grid, where row and column having property `display:flex`.
Now I am creating a dropdown. Using property `display:inline-flex`. But it stretches to full width. Property `inline-flex` does not work. 
I cannot remove the wrapper property

```
.wrapper { 
   display:flex; 
   flex-direction: column; 
   flex-grow: 0; 
   flex-shrink: 0; 
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/JEETPAL/pen/wzkopX

Comment: Please explain a bit more, don't you want it to stretch to the whole page?

Comment: change `min-width` to `width` in `.dropdown`?

Comment: I don't want to stretch the whole dropdown.  I will cover the area accordingly to text. min-width is applied not to sink the component, width is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed the following in your code:

1. Added `align-self: flex-start` to `dropdown` to not extend the whole width (this happens as default value of `align-items` or `align-self` is `stretch`)
2. Changed `min-width` of `dropdown` from 100 to 180px to match that of `ul`

   ```
   .dropdown{
     align-self: flex-start;
     min-width:180px;
   }
   ```

Update codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrRJVg

Comment: thanks. it working.
another one is how i show the clicked value. means the dropdown text replaced by the clicked menu.

Comment: Well, that you can do in javascript - maybe you can show us what you tried  that did not work?